# getDownTime() and getEventTime()

Tags: android, android-event

What is difference between:getEventTime() and getDownTime()? In documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html
Both seems to do the same thing but they output different values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getDownTime` returns the time this series of events started. For example, if you got:

`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, and then `ACTION_MOVE`.

If you call `getDownTime` on this latest event, you will get the time of the `ACTION_DOWN`, which is the event that started the series.

If you call `getEventTime`you will get when the latest `ACTION_MOVE` happened.

Comment: Useful. As test result, the getEventTime() differs among every event.