# Elapsed time between first and second ACTION_DOWN

Tags: java, android, android-gesture

**- The main this I want to accomplish with this question is to distinguish between single and double tap, I want to perform actions depending on single/double tap**

I'm trying to get the elapsed time between the first and next `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764310/measure-elapsed-time-between-two-motionevents-in-android) question where he asked how to get the elapsed time between `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` using `System.nanoTime();` My question is not the same...

Android Image viewer has this function, when you double tab - it zooms in. When you single tap - it hides the tools. I think this is done by measuring the time between the first and next `ACTION_DOWN`

Here is what I currently have:

```
ImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(!gone){
                hide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                gone = true;
            }else{
                hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                gone = false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

The above code will hide the view on every second tap, no matter the elapsed time.

I'm looking for a way to measure the elapsed time between the first `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and the next `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, any ideas?

---

Research I have done:

- difference between [getDownTime() and getEventTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467255/getdowntime-and-geteventtime)
- [Measure elapsed time between two MotionEvents in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764310/measure-elapsed-time-between-two-motionevents-in-android)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

AND COUNTLESS STACKOVERFLOW QUESTIONS.

I still could not find what I was looking for.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Ok so I'm using [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library to handle the zoom of the image view, but this library doesn't support single tab (I could not find docs saying it can). Now I'm trying to figure out a work around for this by detecting a single tap. this is what I have now:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageHolder = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.ImageHolder);
    ImageHolder.setImageURI(myUri);

    ImageHolder.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long lastDown = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(now - lastDown < 500) {// the second touch was 500ms less ago
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                    lastDown = now;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This works fine for detecting the time between first and next `ACTION_DOWN`, but it overrides the functions of the library so the double tap to zoom doesn't work when implementing this.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I have found [this](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) that includes the following gesture class, it is to big to post so please have a look [HERE](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java).

In the info the guy say to use the following to detect a single tap:

```
img.setOnTouchImageViewListener(new TouchImageView.OnTouchImageViewListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMove() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Single", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               

        }
    });
```

But I still have the same problem, it can't distinguish between single and double tap. Single tap is picked up even if I double tap.

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912207/how-to-detect-single-and-double-tap-for-specific-layout-using-setonclicklistener) question, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For this you need to create Custom Gesture Detector and initialize your interface for single Click,Double Click,long pressed .For Simplicity ,
Here is your code :**

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchDetector(mContext,this));


public class MyTouchDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    int position;
    private Context mContext;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private ClickDetector clickDetector;



    public MyTouchDetector(Context mContext, ClickDetector clickDetector) {
        this.mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, this);
        this.clickDetector = clickDetector;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("onDoubleTap :", "" + e.getAction());
        clickDetector.doubleClick();
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("onSingleTap :", "" + e.getAction());
        clickDetector.singleClick();
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        //return super.onDown(e);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);
        Log.d("onLongPress :", "" + e.getAction());

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. How should I call this from my activity? If you have a look at my edit2 that file I mentioned looks similar to this.

Comment: @ClassA >> Steps to call the above code in Activity:
1. Create any interface (ClickDetector in MyCase).
2. implement it into your activity.
3.set TouchListner on your view and pass the instance of MyTouchDetector as shown :=====
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchDetector(mContext,this));
========Extra argument ========
If you want your interface to deliver any data pass that data in constructor of MyTouchDetector.

Comment: @pskink can you please have a look at Edit3 in my question.

Comment: @KumarRaj can you please have a look at Edit3 in my question.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it did what I asked for in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achiev it by counting the system milliseconds. (commented in the if)

```
     ImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
long lastDown = 0;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        long now = System.currentTimeInMillis();
        if(now - lastDown < 500) {
           // the second touch was 500ms less ago 
        }
        lastDown = now;
    }
    return super.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
}
});
```

Comment: sorry, I added return true, but the correct would be return super.onTouc