# List View with two actions in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have list view with two actions one is for new activity and other one is when I long press the list item delete  but the item will not delete mean while when I long press the new activity will be opened automatically..how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to set setOnItemLongClickListener() and setOnItemClickListener()  in the ListView:

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
           int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

            return true;
        }
    }); 




listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    Log.i("Hello!", "Y u no see me?");

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your onLongClick retrun true ,true means that the event is consumed. It is handled. No other click events will be notified.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        return true; // or false
    }
```

or add in xml

```
<ListView android:longClickable="true">
```

or in java class

```
listView.setLongClickable(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage multiple touch my implementing your custom touch listener. Please refers this link for detail.

[Elapsed time between first and second ACTION_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609013/elapsed-time-between-first-and-second-action-down/46621723#46621723)